# Program is supposed to determine if the input number is prime or not

Tags: java

//I am supposed to do it with loops and decision statements, but it's not working. Help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare variables
        Scanner abc;
        abc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int input;
        int divide = 2;
        int count=0;

        //Ask for input
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer to determine if it is prime");
        input = abc.nextInt();

        //Do math
        for (int x=1; x < input; x++) {
            if ((input%divide) == 0)
                count += 1;
            divide = divide + 1;
        }

        if (count == 0)
            System.out.println("It is a prime number");
        else
            System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats not working ? Also you only need to go to square root of the number

Comment: Talking strictly about effectiveness, you can first check if it's not even by checking `if (input % 2 == 0)` (if it is, it is not prime of course) and then check only odd numbers (starting with 3) up to the square root of the checked number.

Comment: I'd do some research; this problem has been solved by ancient Greeks.  Look for sieve of Eratosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @duffymo i think he's looking for why his implementation of the naive algorithm is not working, rather than for a better algorithm

Comment: I understand, but he might want to be aware that a better algorithm has existed for thousands of years.

Comment: It's only a better algorithm if you plan on calling (say) isPrime() a fairly large number of times with input limited to a fairly small range.  Then you can compute the answers once, keep them in an array, and consult the array each time.  If you're only calling isPrime() once it is not helpful.

Comment: @duffymo while there do exist better algorithms, the one you chose cite is good for generating all primes up to a range rather than for testing whether a specific number is prime. makes sense?

Comment: Actually I wouldn't do either.  I'd load known values into a table and check that.  For larger values I'd use Riemann approximation.

Comment: close voters == liars. the code demonstrates minimal understanding & the problem was extremely specific as the answers show. please be honest in your reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, for the last iteration, `x = input - 1`, but that means `divide = input` (since `divide` was one greater in the beginning, and you increment both once per iteration of the loop), so count will actually be equal to `1` if the number is prime, not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int x=2; x < input; x++)`  (change `x=1` to `x=2`)

otherwise you end up trying to divide 5 by 5 to test if 5 is prime

Comment: actually this is correct, since `divided` is always one greater than `x` the last loop iteration will have divided equal to input lol

Comment: @ay89 you probably do not see that x controls the number of loop iterations, which causes the last value of the `divide` variable to hit the number itself.

Comment: @jlars62 thanks. of course it's correct! i was pointing the OP to the exact error in his *intended* logic. there are dozens of ways to do it different.y

Answer (score 1):

You're counting the number of divisors; all you need to do is determine if there is at least one divisor. Here's a better algorithm:

```
function isPrime(n)
    if n is even
        return n == 2
    d := 3
    while d * d <= n
        if n % d == 0
            return False
        d := d + 2
    return True
```

I discuss this algorithm, among others in the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which includes implementations in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `count` is supposed to count the number of factors of `input` not counting 1 and `input`.  For readability, I'd recommend using a name like numOfFactors instead of `count`.

Given that, now look at your loop and answer these questions.  I'm not going to give you the answer.  (Yes, you can get the answer by looking at others' comments, but I think you will learn more by answering these questions anyway.)

(1) What are `x` and `divide` the first time you go through the loop, at the beginning of the loop?

(2) If you look at what happens to `x` and `divide`, there's a simple relationship between `x` and `divide` at the beginning of *each* time through the loop.  What is it?

(3) What is `x` the *last* time you go through the loop?

(4) Based on the answers to #2 and #3, what is `divide` at the beginning of the last time through the loop?  What will input%divide be equal to?

That's why it isn't working.  Figure that out first.  Then we can talk about how to can make it work more efficiently.

MORE: OK, I'll say one more thing.  If all you care about is whether `count` is zero or not, you can quit your loop as soon as you find a factor.  Like this:

```
if ((input%divide) == 0)
{
    count += 1;
    break;
}
```

(And if you do it that way, then instead of `count` you should use a `boolean foundAFactor` because all it says is whether you found a factor, not how many there are.)

But if you really want to know the exact number of factors, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Hello do it like this:

```
for(int i = input-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if((input % i) == 0) {
            if(i == 1)
                System.out.println("is a prime");
            else
                System.out.println("is not a prime");
            break;
    }       
 }
```